# Python skimage.feature.hog function, meaning of parameter pixels_per_cell and cells_per_block

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I'm having troubles using the `hog` function from `skimage.feature`. I couldn't find detailed documentation, nor useful blogs explaining the parameters `pixels_per_cell` and `cells_per_block`.

I use HOG to extract feature from MNIST dataset (all images are 28*28), and I set `pixels_per_cell = (2,2)`, `cells_per_block = (14,14)`, `orientation = 8`.

I thought there ought to be only one block in the extracted feature, because 2*14=28, which uses up all pixels of the image. But clearly I am wrong. `hog` returns an array of shape `(1568,)` (1568=14*14*8).

More strangely, if I set `pixels_per_cell = (2,2)`, `cells_per_block = (7,7)`, `orientation = 8`, I get a huge array of shape `(25088,)`.

What's the correct usage of the two parameters `pixels_per_cell` and `cells_per_block`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of block and cell are presented well in the following tutorials [1](https://customers.pyimagesearch.com/lesson-sample-histogram-of-oriented-gradients-and-car-logo-recognition/) and [2](https://learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/). One thing will help to understand the resultant feature verctor shape is to turn off the flatten option using `feature_vector = False` in the passed arguments to `hog`.